# Ativar JButton a partir de seleção em JTable e remover o foco inicial da tabela

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Eu tenho uma janela com um `JTable`, onde só é válida a seleção de uma linha inteira, e não de apenas um campo. A questão é que a janela já abre com a primeira linha selecionada, e eu gostaria de desativar isso.

Nessa mesma janela eu tenho um `JButton` que já é desativado na hora da sua criação, porém eu gostaria de ativá-lo assim que o usuário selecionar qualquer linha do `JTable` ...

Resumindo : Como eu desativo a seleção automática da linha do `JTable` no momento que a janela abre ? Como ativar um botão quando o usuário selecionar qualquer linha desse mesmo `JTable` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para evitar a seleção automática, você precisa mudar o foco da tabela ao abrir a janela.

Se sua classe tiver herdando de `JFrame`:

```
this.requestFocus();
```

Se tiver inciando uma janela a partir de uma variavel:

```
meuFrame.requestFocus();
```

O `requestFocus()` irá alterar o foco para sua janela principal, evitando assim que o `JTable` já surja com a primeira linha selecionada.

Para ativar o botão somente quando houver uma seleção, tente o abaixo:

```
this.tabela.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                ListSelectionModel lsm = (ListSelectionModel) e.getSource();
                //altera os botoes para ativados somente se houver linha selecionada
                myButton.setEnabled(!lsm.isSelectionEmpty());
            }
        });
```

Dessa forma a ativação do botão fica dependente se existe ou não algum campo/linha selecionado na tabela.

Comment: @DanielSantos a solução conseguiu resolver o seu problema?

Comment: Desculpe a demora para responder ! Resolveu metade dos meus problemas haha. O trecho que trata de ativar o botão funcionou perfeitamente. O problema é no `requestFocus()`... Eu coloquei ele no construtor do `JFrame`, e não foi, depois eu fiz esse mesmo comando no controller da janela (que é a classe que é "chamada") dessa forma : `gridCliente.requestFocus();` e também não funcionou !

Comment: @DanielSantos como não funcionou? Não está retirando o foco incial da tabela?

Comment: Exatamente ! A janela continua selecionando a primeira linha do `JTable` ao iniciar  ...

Comment: Poderia mostrar como está o código da sua janela? Poste no pastebin.com

Comment: http://pastebin.com/zdP39qAA está ai, o mesmo comando nas duas classes !

Comment: @DanielSantos você construiu essa tela inteira por linha de código apenas ou usou algum construtor de telas, como window builder no eclipse ou o netbeans?

Comment: Construí tudo, linha por linha no eclipse ...

Comment: @DanielSantos teste com a mudança que fiz aqui http://pastebin.com/T6UKmZzj

Comment: Não foi cara, esses objetos são do pacote `awt`, certo ?

Comment: @DanielSantos na verdade só adicionei um listener pra seu frame mudar o foco. Olha sinceramente, sem testar o código todo fica dificil até tentar descobrir o real problema, fiz varios testes aqui e em todos o foco foi alterado. Como ultima tentativa, tente adicionar isso logo após a criação da sua tabela: `suaTable.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();`

Comment: Não foi também cara, mas agradeço seu esforço !

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

class SelectTableExample
        extends     JFrame
        implements  ListSelectionListener
{
    // Instance attributes used in this example
   private  JPanel      topPanel;
   private  JTable      table;
   private  JScrollPane scrollPane;
   private  JButton     button;

    // Constructor of main frame
   public SelectTableExample()
   {
    // Set the frame characteristics
      setTitle( "Simple Table Application" );
      setSize( 300, 200 );
      setBackground( Color.gray );

    // Create a panel to hold all other components
      topPanel = new JPanel();
      topPanel.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
      getContentPane().add( topPanel );

    // Create columns names
      String columnNames[] = { "Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3" };

    // Create some data
      String dataValues[][] =
         {
         { "12", "234", "67" },
         { "-123", "43", "853" },
         { "93", "89.2", "109" },
         { "279", "9033", "3092" }
         };

    // Create a new table instance
      table = new JTable( dataValues, columnNames );

      // Block cell edition
      table.setModel(
            new DefaultTableModel(dataValues, columnNames) {
               public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) { 
                  return false;
               }
            });

        // Handle the listener
      ListSelectionModel selectionModel = table.getSelectionModel();
      selectionModel.addListSelectionListener( this );

    // Add the table to a scrolling pane
      scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
      topPanel.add( scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER );

      button = new JButton("continuar");
      button.setEnabled(false);
      topPanel.add( button, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
   }

    // Enable button for list selection changes
   public void valueChanged( ListSelectionEvent event )
   {
    // See if this is a valid table selection
      if( event.getSource() == table.getSelectionModel()
                    && event.getFirstIndex() >= 0 )
      {
         button.setEnabled(true);
      }
   }

    // Main entry point for this example
   public static void main( String args[] )
   {
    // Create an instance of the test application
      SelectTableExample mainFrame  = new SelectTableExample();
      mainFrame.setVisible( true );
   }
}
```

Comment: Apesar da sua resposta ter a solução, respostas assim, jogando um código aleatório e solto sem explicação não são boas respostas. Lembre-se que quem pergunta pode nem sempre saber o que precisa fazer.

Comment: @DiegoF peço mil desculpas, não percebi isso. Minha intenção era ajudar. Peço desculpa também ao Daniel Santos.

Comment: Ingrid sim, fora de mim questionar isso, mas muitas vezes a pessoa que pergunta pode não conseguir identificar a solução, alias, outra pessoa que cair nessa resposta, pode não entender nada. É importante explicar brevemente(nao precisa escrever um artigo) como a pessoa resolve a solução, pense que sua resposta agora estará ajudando o AP, mas no futuro, muitas outras pessoas que lerem no site :)

Comment: @DiegoF é verdade, tem toda razão =) Nas próximas respostas que puder ajudar vou também fazer uma breve explicação. Obrigada pela informação!

Comment: @IngridFarabulini Eu até entendi sua resposta, mas é como o Diego disse, uma pessoa mais "inexperiente" pode ficar olhando durante muito tempo pra sua resposta e não achar a solução, mas ta perdoada ! O que vale é a intenção !

Comment: @DanielSantos obrigada Daniel pela sua compreensão, minha intenção realmente foi ajudar. Vou procurar melhorar minhas respostas, me desculpe.